# Use Exists with a Column of Query Result?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-like, exists

I have 2 tables.
One is bom_master:

| CHILD | PARENT |
| --- | --- |
| 1-111 | 66-6666 |
| 2-222 | 77-7777 |
| 2-222 | 88-8888 |
| 3-333 | 99-9999 |

Another one is library:

| FileName | Location |
| --- | --- |
| 66-6666_A.step | S:\ABC |
| 77-7777_C~K1.step | S:\DEF |

And I want to find out if the child's parents have related files in the library.
Expected Result:

| CHILD | PARENT | FileName |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-111 | 66-6666 | 66-6666_A.step |
| 2-222 | 77-7777 | 77-7777_C~K1.step |

Tried below lines but return no results. Any comments? Thank you.

```
WITH temp_parent_PN(parentPN)
AS
(
    SELECT 
    [PARENT]
    FROM [bom_master]
    where [bom_master].[CHILD] in ('1-111','2-222')
)
SELECT s.[filename]
FROM [library] s
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 
    *
    FROM temp_parent_PN b
    where s.[filename] LIKE '%'+b.[parentPN]+'%'
)
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) I rolled back the edit to remove the markdown tables and add the image.

Comment: The query you have provided does return results with the sample data you provided ([example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_skpe9vu)) so it is unclear what your actual issue is. Are you are to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). For what it is worth though, this is a terrible schema - if your library is linked to other entities then there should be a foreign key column and not reliant on text appearing in file names

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have to use exists. The problem is that you need to substring to match the join.
Have a look at this:

```
SELECT b.CHILD, b.PARENT, l.[FileName] 
FROM [bom_master] b 
INNER JOIN [library] l ON b.PARENT  = SUBSTRING(l.FileName,1,7)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But the length is not always 7, e.g. it is not always '66-6666' or '77-7777'. There are '66-6666666' and '6666-6666666'.

Comment: @user987654 then you need to make sure that your sample data covers all edge cases.

Comment: This edge case is also relevant to your pattern matching on file names. If you had a file name `6666-6666666_A.step`, then that is going to match with `66-6666`, `66-6666666`, and `6666-6666666`. The latter is avoidable if you know the file name will start with the `PARENT` but the first two would require additional rules on filename formatting to correctly break out the relevant part.

Comment: LEFT(str,7) is better than SUBSTRING(str,1,7)

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one level of dependencies use the join solution proposed by dimis164.

If you have deeper levels you could use recursive queries allowed by WITH clause (
ref. [WITH common_table_expression (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)).

This is a sample with one more level of relation in bom_master (you could then join the result of the recursive query with library as you need).

```sql
DECLARE @bom_master TABLE (Child NVARCHAR(MAX), Parent NVARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO @bom_master VALUES
    ('1-111', '66-666'),
    ('2-222', '77-777'),
    ('3-333', '88-888'),
    ('4-444', '99-999'),
    ('A-AAA', '1-111');

WITH 
    leaf AS ( -- Get the leaf elements (elements without a child)
        SELECT Child FROM @bom_master b1
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @bom_master b2 WHERE b2.Parent = b1.Child) ),
    rec(Child, Parent, Level) AS (
        SELECT b.Child, b.Parent, Level = 1 
        FROM @bom_master b
        JOIN leaf l ON l.Child = b.Child
        UNION ALL
        SELECT rec.Child, b.Parent, Level = rec.Level + 1
        FROM rec
        JOIN @bom_master b
        ON b.Child = rec.Parent )
SELECT * FROM rec
```